Live data dictonary on Websocket Server hosted GCP App engine behaves unusually
So I have a web socket server hosted on GCP app engine, In the server I have a global dict which i keep storing to keep a track of connections.
The problem is even with so many logs its hard to keep track of connection dict changing
Firstly is it good practice to keep global array or dict and server checks it for active connections?
import asyncio
import logging
import uvicorn
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from asyncio import Lock

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = FastAPI()

# Dictionary to store connections
connections = {}
lock = Lock()  # Lock to manage access to the connections dictionary

@app.websocket("/ask")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    serial_number = None  # Initialize serial_number to track the client
    t = None
    try:
        while True:
            # Receive data from the client
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            print(f"Raw data received: {data}") 
            data = json.loads(data)
            print(f"json {data}")
            print(connections)
            t = data["type"]
            sno = data["serialno"]
            if data["type"] == "client":
                serial_number = data["serialno"]
                async with lock:
                    connections[serial_number] = websocket
                    print(connections)
                print("Client connected:", serial_number)
            elif data["type"] == "mobile":
                print(f"Serial number: {sno}")
                print(connections)
                async with lock:
                    if sno in connections:
                        print(f"Type of connections[sno]: {type(connections[sno])}")
                        print(f"Type of data['msg']: {type(data['msg'])}, Value: {data['msg']}")
                        if isinstance(connections[sno], WebSocket):
                            print("Sending message to client...")
                            try:
                                await connections[sno].send_text("guava")  # Send the message to the client
                            except Exception as send_error:
                                logging.error(f"Error sending message: {send_error}")
                                logging.error(f"connections[sno]: {connections[sno]}")
                                logging.error(f"data['msg']: {data['msg']}")
                        else:
                            print(f"Error: connections[sno] is not a WebSocket object: {type(connections[sno])}")
                    else:
                        print("No connection found for serial number:", sno)
            elif t == "ping":
                print("before sending")
                connections[sno] = websocket
                print(connections)
                print("sending pong")
                await connections[sno].send_text("pong")
                print(connections)
            else:
                print("This is else print")

            # Log the received data
            logging.info(f"Data received: {data}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error handling message: {e}")
    
    finally:
        logging.info("Connection closing for serial_number: %s", serial_number)
        if (t == "client" ) and serial_number:
            async with lock:
                if serial_number in connections:
                    del connections[serial_number]
                    logging.info(f"Client {serial_number} disconnected and removed from connections")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)


That is my server file, Client gets connected stores connection and wait for Mobile to send data to server which transfers it to corresponding client device.
**Second question The above code works for most cases correct, ie if i call this server with a simple client **
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def websocket_client():
    uri = "ws://rasd-8bd8c.uc.r.appspot.com/ask"
    
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        # Initial message to the server
        message = {
            "type" : "client",
            "serialno" : "123",
            "msg" : "wow"
        }
        p = {
            "type" : "ping",
            "serialno" : "123",
            "msg" : "pong"
        }
        jsonobj = json.dumps(message)
        jsonping = json.dumps(p)
        await websocket.send(jsonobj)
        print(f"Sent message: {jsonobj}")

        # Create a task to send pings every 2 minutes
        async def send_ping():
            while True:
                await websocket.send(jsonping)
                print(f"Sent ping: {jsonping}")
                await asyncio.sleep(10)

        # Start the ping task
        ping_task = asyncio.Task(send_ping())

        # Continuously listen for messages from the server
        try:
            while True:
                response = await websocket.recv()
                print(f"Received message from server: {response}")
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("Connection closed by the server")
            

# Run the client
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket_client())


**So this works now if i go to the line which reads as
ping_task = asyncio.Task(send_ping())
If i use create task it works but if i replace it with ensure_future it disrupts everything, ie the client gets connected to server but connection dict in server some how becomes empty.**
Third question, So if i open my mobile app[ie that is it gets connected to server and looks if it has some corresponding client in connection and it dosent find any lets say because client still did not get connected. Now lets say the client gets connected so the connection dict should get updated and if i than send data from mobile app it should go to server and come to client but if i open the connection from mobile first and than connect client, it keeps saying the dict connections in server is empty but thats not the case because my client got connected and thus dict had to be updated gloablly.
What is going wrong here?
**
Fourth question, Its my first time playing with these stuff anything which is not a good practice you guys can share the correct way**
Tried alot of stuff, generally logs, but with server hosted on gcp its hard to even catch stuff in logs.
Other than that i have work arounds but i wanted to find and understand the stuff.

Do you use App Engine Flex or App Engine Standard?

flex, I think you are asking because of create task and ensure_future and python version, so this issue is happening on client side which is hosted in device not app engine

No, it's because Websocket are not supported in App Engine Standard. I'm not sure of the full compatibility with App Engine Flex. I always recommend to use Cloud Run Service instead of App Engine Flex, when applicable. And Cloud Run is compliant with Websocket, i'm sure it will work there

@Fawwaz Ali Can you please try to enable Session Affinity by following
this documentation?
